# Lit TypeScript decorator issue

Tags: typescript, decorator, lit

I try to get into TypeScript by writing TS based Lit Elements, refactoring a very small project of mine.

However it starts to get frustrating since I don't see what's wrong with this code since it's reduced to nearly the same as a HelloWorld example and still gives errors:

```js
import { LitElement, css, html } from 'lit';
import { customElement, property } from 'lit/decorators.js';

@customElement('student-ids')
export class StudentIds extends LitElement {

  @property()
  name = 'Somebody';

  render() {
    return html`
      <h1>Classroom Ids</h1>
      <p>Hello, ${this.name}!</p>
    `;
  }
}
```

In Chrome I get the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: The following properties on element student-ids will not trigger updates 
as expected because they are set using class fields: name. Native class fields and some compiled output 
will overwrite accessors used for detecting changes. 
See https://lit.dev/msg/class-field-shadowing for more information.
    at StudentIds.performUpdate (reactive-element.ts:1302:17)
    at StudentIds.scheduleUpdate (reactive-element.ts:1261:17)
    at StudentIds.__enqueueUpdate (reactive-element.ts:1233:25)
```

Taking a look at problems my IDE sees, I get the impression that my project is missing some packages or settings to solve this, since within the IDE I see errors at the decorators:

- @customElement(): `Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression. The runtime will invoke the decorator with 2 arguments, but the decorator expects 1.ts(1238)`
- @property(): `Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression. Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Object | ClassElement'.ts(1240)`

Any hints on what to change to solve this issue?

Comment: I remember decorators being experimental and TS5 introducing a few breaking changes, what version of typescript are you using? Has lit been updated to support it?

Comment: In your `tsconfig.json`, have you set `experimentalDecorators` to true and `useDefineForClassFields` to false as per https://lit.dev/docs/components/decorators/#decorators-typescript ?

Comment: I don't do Lit, but isn't ``name`` a standard property on ``HTMLElement``

Comment: Was indeed using TS5, but saw that when I create a new Vite TS/Lit project they too use version 5, so that shouldn't be the cause of the problem.
I also set the `experimentalDecorators` to true. That indeed fixed the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Updated answer for Lit 3.0

The prior answer still works, however since Lit 3.0, standard decorator support has been added. Make sure you are using TypeScript ≥ 5.2

This means if you are on Lit version 3 or higher, you can now set `experimentalDecorators` and `useDefineForClassFields` to their default values.

This will require you use standard decorators and add the `accessor` keyword. For your example above, all you need is the `accessor` keyword:

```js
  @property()
  accessor name = 'Somebody';
```

If you want more details about migrating from experimental decorators to standard decorators, there is an upgrade guide: https://lit.dev/docs/v3/releases/upgrade/#standard-decorator-migration

## Prior answer (for Lit 2 and Lit 3):

When using decorators in Lit, make sure to follow the guidance here: https://lit.dev/docs/components/decorators/#decorators-typescript

In your TypeScript `tsconfig.json`, make sure to set `experimentalDecorators` to `true` and `useDefineForClassFields` to `false`.